# When loading a JSON body receiving error: "expecting ',' delimiter: line 1 column 18 (char 17)"?

Tags: python, json, dictionary

```
import json
a_json = '{"some_body":" 
[{"someId":"189353945391","EId":"09358039485","someUID":10,"LegalId":"T743","cDate":"202452","rAmount":{"aPa":{"am":1500,"currId":"UD"},"cost":{"amount":1000,"currId":"US"},"lPrice":{"amount":100,"currId":"DD"}},"tes":{"ant":0,"currId":"US"},"toount":{"amnt":0,"currId":"US"},"toount":{"amt":210,"currId":"US"},"bry":"US","pay":[{"pId":"7111","axt":{"amt":2000,"currId":"US"},"mKey":"CSD"}],"oItems":[{"iIndex":0,"rId":"69823","provId":"001","segEntityId":"C001","per":{"vae":1,"ut":"MOS"},"pct":{"prod":"748"},"revType":"REW","rAmount":{"aPaid":{"amt":90000,"currId":"US"},"xt":{"amt":0,"currId":"USD"},"lPrice":{"amt":90000,"currId":"US"}},"stion":{"sLocal":"094u5304","eLocal":"3459340"},"tx":{"adt":{"adet":0,"currId":"US"},"era":"werTIC"}}}]"}'
```

Above is the JSON I am trying to iterate through. Kind of a weird JSON. I want to take that JSON string and turn it into a python dictionary, so I can better iterate it. I put a single quote mark on either side and used json.loads to turn it into a python dictionary.

```
loaded_body = json.loads(a_json)
```

And I am calling the only key from the beginning "some_body" which will get the contents of the entire body. When I run the following command `print(loaded_body)` I get back the error:

> expecting ',' delimiter: line 1 column 18 (char 17)

Ultimately once that error is resolved, this is what I am trying to access:

```
desired_item =loaded_body['oItems'][0]['rAmount']['aPa']['currId']
```

Thanks

Comment: Does your file actually contain the `“` character instead of a `"` character?

Comment: Appears that it does, does that make a difference? When I did a character search in notepad it recognizes both as the same thing.

Comment: @JonClements I opened notepad and replaced all ```“``` with ```"``` and now the error msg reads: ```Expecting``` ```','``` ```delimiter: line 1 column 18 (char 17)```... I updated my post to have only ```"```

Comment: First of all, I doubt your `a_json` string is split across lines as you have shown and if not, you should edit your question and correct this. Second, you have in this string immediately following the colon character(':') a `"` character. So if this is supposed to be a string literal, the `"` characters that are within the string should all be preceded by double backslash characters, i.e. \\.

Comment: @Booboo new to JSON data and apis. The original JSON had a bunch of ```\n``` and ```\``` and I assumed this wasn't required and if I just have it as one long horizontal string it would work. Should I keep the ```\n``` and the ```\``` or should they be replaced by something?

Comment: You should keep the string as it was originally and you should post it that way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you're treating the content of `some_body` as a string since it's enclosed with double quotes. But inside of that string there's also quotation marks and now it's interpreted that the content of `some_body` is `[{` and then it breaks because directly after that is `someId` rather than a comma. Thus the error:

> expecting ',' delimiter: line 1 column 18 (char 17)

If the content of `some_body` was actually meant to be a string then all the double quotes inside of it should be preceded by a double backslash (`\\`) although in this case you'd have to parse the JSON twice - first the entire `a_json` string and then the content of `some_body`. However I think it would be easier to just remove the double quotes around the content of `some_body`.

```
a_json = '{"some_body":
[{"someId":"189353945391","EId":"09358039485","someUID":10,"LegalId":"T743","cDate":"202452","rAmount":{"aPa":{"am":1500,"currId":"UD"},"cost":{"amount":1000,"currId":"US"},"lPrice":{"amount":100,"currId":"DD"}},"tes":{"ant":0,"currId":"US"},"toount":{"amnt":0,"currId":"US"},"toount":{"amt":210,"currId":"US"},"bry":"US","pay":[{"pId":"7111","axt":{"amt":2000,"currId":"US"},"mKey":"CSD"}],"oItems":[{"iIndex":0,"rId":"69823","provId":"001","segEntityId":"C001","per":{"vae":1,"ut":"MOS"},"pct":{"prod":"748"},"revType":"REW","rAmount":{"aPaid":{"amt":90000,"currId":"US"},"xt":{"amt":0,"currId":"USD"},"lPrice":{"amt":90000,"currId":"US"}},"stion":{"sLocal":"094u5304","eLocal":"3459340"},"tx":{"adt":{"adet":0,"currId":"US"},"era":"werTIC"
}}]}]}'
```

Also note that there's a missing closing square bracket near the end.

In your original string:

```
"werTIC"}}}]"}
```

Which should probably be:

```
"werTIC"}}]}]}
```

Now the desired item should look like this (I assume that `'aPa'` was meant to be `'aPaid'`):

```
desired_item = loaded_body['some_body'][0]['oItems'][0]['rAmount']['aPaid']['currId']
print(desired_item)
US
```

Comment: super helpful answer! My original JSON had '\n' and '\' throughout it. I read that the '\' should be two, so I replaced in the json everywhere that had a '\' with two like so: '\\' when I run my code with the ```}}]}]}``` at the end an error msg pops up and says ```"json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Unterminated string starting at: line 1 column 9 (char 8)```

Comment: Also, is it a rule that the outer parts must have ```'``` on either side for this to work. And as for every thing inside it must have ```"```. Also I guess my JSON is a bit strange because the "some_body" part is followed by a colon and then a double-quote mark on either side of the contents of the "some_body" key's value, not sure what to make of that, but this is how the JSON came in.